# NebulaGraph database: What is the appropriate setting for replica_factor?

Tags: nebula-graph

Can I set `replica_factor` as any number in CREATE SPACE statements?
Is it better to set this parameter higher the more machines we use for storage?

The NebulaGraph documentation describes this parameter as follows:
Specifies the number of replicas in the cluster. The suggested number is 3 in a production environment and 1 in a test environment. The replica number must be an odd number for the need of quorum-based voting. The default value is 1.

But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, the replication was done via [raft](https://raft.github.io/), that's the reason why replica factor cannot be even.

Normally, either 1 or 3 is the value you would like to give for 99% of cases, where 1 comes without HA and 3 can suffer from single-point failure.

See more from [here](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/1.introduction/3.nebula-graph-architecture/4.storage-service/)